# Colouring Balck and White Pic on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, design-principles

**This, I want.**

[image]

**This, I have tried.**

I could simply make an overlay with 20% opacity, you would think, but this method reduces the clarity of the effect tremendously.

I tried colour tone/Saturation, but it only changes certain colours within the face into other colours.

But an overall green or red, I don't know how to get.

Shouldn't be that difficult though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult at all. There are a few different ways to achieve something like this in photoshop. I would suggest that the simplest way is to have you black and white image on one layer and fill the layer above it with the flat colour that you want and then set transparency mode of the colour layer to MULTIPLY in the layers palette. Job done.

Comment: I feel like there is a slight difference to the picture above, but it is really good. So, thanks. What exactly does multiply do?